# Find the multicast group a datagram was sent to

Tags: node.js, multicast

I'm building a node app which records a multicast RTP stream off a network.  Here's my code:

```
var server = dgram.createSocket({type: 'udp4',reuseAddr: true});

server.on('listening', function () {
            var address = server.address();
            server.addMembership("<the multicast group>");
            console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    });

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    // do some stuff
});
```

This process is not the only process receiving multicast datagrams on this port on this host (thus the `reuseAddr: true`).

When I do this, message events for every multicast datagram which hits the interface on this machine, not just the one this process has subscribed to.  Not an issue - so long as I can filter out the datagrams I don't care about.

Unfortunately, I don't know the actual host that's transmitting the packets I care about, I only know the multicast group.  So if I look at `remote`, I get something like:

```
{ address: '10.10.11.6', family: 'IPv4', port: 5004, size: 84 }
```

Which doesn't tell me which multicast group the datagram was sent to. The payload itself also doesn't give me any clues after decoding it.

Are there any methods by which I can filter just the multicast groups which I care about?

Comment: I didn't get it, if you call `addMembership("<the multicast group>");`, then you should only receive packets from that group.

Comment: Actually, I get packets from any multicast group to which the process was subscribed - however a single host may be sending to multiple groups separate streams, and I need to be able to tell which packet came from which group.